# Cannot run python script that uses loguru

Tags: python, loguru

I couldn't find any similar SO threads, so i decided to create a new one.
I'd like to use loguru in my python scripts, but i encountered a problem with running them through url
http://host:port/some/dirs/script.py
Running script like so gives me an internal server error
Server log says:

> [Thu Aug 25 09:30:51.589337 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 18553] [client ...] AH01215:   File "/some/dirs/script.py", line 3, in <module>
> [Thu Aug 25 09:30:51.591079 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 18553] [client ...] End of script output before headers: script.py

But i can run script successfully with PyCharm or in terminal.
I suppose problem with server configuration, but i can't really change anything, since it's my work server (apache btw).
I would very much appreciate any info on this subject

Comment: Possibly your script crashes and there is no response created ?

Comment: Apache expects web-server headers like `print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")` as the first output. Please see tutorials like: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm. But I recommend using WSGI instead of CGI.

Comment: @MortenB, yes, i have those, but since imports must be at the top of the file, and i have an issue with importing loguru, it results into End of script output before headers. I have other scripts, where i print headers after import statements, and those work fine

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, as i stated above, script runs successfully if i use terminal.
It is a simple test script
`from loguru import logger
print(f'Content-Type: text/html')
print()
logger.add('logs/local_test.log', format='{time} {level} {message}', level='DEBUG')
logger.debug('This is a debug message')`

Comment: @Edward Vlasenko: This seems not to be a valid CGI script.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, i fail to see the problem with the script. I'm not sure what you mean by CGI script. I just want to be able to run my python script using cron or let somebody run my script using a link. It works fine usually, but importing loguru crashes my script execution

Comment: You need to debug: Is the Python interpreter used within Apache able to import loguru ? Can the logger write into `logs/local_test.log`, what is `logs` relative too (I haven't used Apache since decades) ? ...

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, I use the same python3.8 interpreter to run my flask app, where i also use loguru and it works fine. If i run `python3.8 script.py` it will successfully make a record  to logs/local_test.log. logs/ and script.py are in the same directory